# Merge a list of dataframes together by column value

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, cbind

I have a list of dataframes `df_list` that looks like this:

```
 head(df_list[[1]])
       score    name  rank
 921   9718     aba   921
 346   11387    aca   346

head(df_list[[2]]
       score    name  rank
 1080  9023     aba   1080
 156   12276    aca   156
```

and  I would like to merge them together on the name, so that I get something like

```
       score.1  rank.1   score.2   rank.2
 aba   9718     921      9023      1080 
 aca   11387    346      12276     156
```

I tried using do.call and cbind like

```
tmp <- do.call("cbind", df_list)
```

however, this gives me

```
head(tmp)
      score    name  rank   score   name   rank
921   9718     aba   921    9718    aba    1080 
346   11387    aca   346    11387   aca    156
```

and when I try to get the rankings with `tmp[tmp$rank]` I can only get the first column named rank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `merge`

```
 merge(dt1,dt2,by='name', suffixes = c(".1",".2"))
  name score.1 rank.1 score.2 rank.2
1  aba    9718    921    9023   1080
2  aca   11387    346   12276    156
```

If you have more than 2 elements:

```
ll <- list(dt1,dt2)

Merge <- 
  function(x,y)
merge(x,y,by='name', suffixes = c(".1",".2"))
Reduce(Merge,ll)
 name score.1 rank.1 score.2 rank.2
1  aba    9718    921    9023   1080
2  aca   11387    346   12276    156
```

Comment: works, except suffix needs to be changed for more than 2 elements

Comment: @NiekdeKlein you can see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list-simultaneously) to deal with the naming problem.. I marked your question as duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

`cbind()` is doing exactly what it is meant to do, placing the columns side-by-side. If you want to merge them, you need to use the `merge()` function.

If your data always has the same observations (in the same order) then cbind would be appropriate. In that case you just remove the `name` column from all data.frames except the first and rename the other columns tagging them with a counter.

Comment: +1! yes in general! but it is always better to provide some code with your answer.